# What is the width argument in position_dodge?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[The documentation of `position_dodge`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) does not explain what exactly is this `width` argument

1. Whose width does it specify?
2. What's the "unit"?
3. What's the default value?

The default value is `width = NULL`, but trial and error shows that `width = 0.9` seems to produce the default effect (see postscript). However, [I couldn't find where such default value is set in `ggplot2` source code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/5f4af9eafed9cbd7e3c84285fe3c9047f1ccb17d/R/position-dodge.r). Thus,

4. Could you explain how the default dodge is implemented in `ggplot2` code?

The spirit of the question is to allow `ggplot2` users to find appropriate `width` values without trial and error.
PS:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x, y, fill = factor(group)), 
           position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity")

ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x, y, fill = factor(group)), 
           position = position_dodge(0.9), stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I will first give very brief answers to your three main questions. Then I walk through several examples to illustrate the answers more thoroughly.

1. *Whose width does it specify*?
   The width of the `geom` elements to be dodged.
2. *What's the "unit*"?
   The actual *or* the virtual width in data units of the elements to be dodged.
3. *What's the default value*?
   If you don't *set* the dodging `width` explicitly, but rely on the default value, `position_dodge(width = NULL)` (or just `position = "dodge"`), the dodge width which is used is the actual width in data units of the element to be dodged.

I believe your fourth question is too broad for SO. Please refer to the code of [`collide`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/position-collide.r) and [`dodge`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/5f4af9eafed9cbd7e3c84285fe3c9047f1ccb17d/R/position-dodge.r) and, if needed, ask a *new, more specific* question.

---

Based on the dodge width of the element (together with its original horizontal position and the number of elements which are stacked), new center positions (`x`) of each element, and new widths (`xmin`, `xmax` positions) are calculated. The elements are shifted horizontally just far enough not to overlap with adjacent elements. Obviously, wide elements needs to be shifted more than narrow elements in order to avoid overlap.

To get a better feeling for dodging in general and the use of the `width` argument in particular, I show some examples. We start with a simple dodged bar plot, with default dodging; we can use either `position = "dodge"` or the more explicit `position = position_dodge(width = NULL)`

```
# some toy data
df <- data.frame(x = 1,
                 y = 1,
                 grp = c("A", "B"))

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = grp)) + theme_minimal()
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position = "dodge")
           # which is the same as:
           # position = position_dodge(width = NULL))
```

[image]

So (1) whose `width` is it in `position_dodge` and (2) what is the unit?

In `?position_dodge` we can read:

> `width`: Dodging width, when *different* to the width of the individual        elements

Thus, if we use the *default* `width`, i.e. `NULL`, the dodging calculations are based on *the width of the individual elements*.

So a trivial answer to your first question, "*Whose width does it specify*?", would be: *the width of the individual elements*.

But of course we then wonder, what is "the width of the individual elements"? Let's start with the bars. From `?geom_bar`:

> `width`: Bar width. By default, set to 90% of the resolution of the data

A new question arises: what is resolution? Let's check `?ggplot2::resolution`:

> The resolution is is the smallest non-zero distance between adjacent values. If there is only one unique value [like in our example], then the resolution is defined to be one.

We try:

```
resolution(df$x)
# [1] 1
```

Thus, the default bar width in this example is `0.9 * 1 = 0.9`

We may check this by looking at the data `ggplot` uses to render the bars on the plot using `ggplot_build`. We create a plot object with a stacked barplot, with bars of default width.

```
p2 <- p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "stack")
```

The relevant slot in the object is `$data`, which is a list with one element for each layer in the plot, in the same order as they appear in the code. In this example, we only have one layer, i.e. `geom_bar`, so let's look at the first slot:

```
ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]

#      fill x y label PANEL group ymin ymax xmin xmax colour size linetype alpha
# 1 #F8766D 1 1     A     1     1    0    1 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
# 2 #00BFC4 1 2     B     1     2    1    2 0.55 1.45     NA  0.5        1    NA
```

Each row contains data to 'draw' a single bar. As you can see, the width of the bars are all 0.9 (`xmax - xmin = 0.9`). Thus, the width of the *stacked* bars, to be used in the calculations of the new dodged positions and widths, is `0.9`.

---

In the previous example, we used the default bar width, together with the default dodge width. Now let's make the bar slightly wider than the default width above (0.9). Use the `width` argument in `geom_bar` to explicitly *set* the (stacked) bar width to e.g. 1. We try to use the same dodge width as above (`position_dodge(width = 0.9)`). Thus, while we have *set* the *actual* bar width to be 1, the dodge calculations are made *as if* the bars are 0.9 wide. Let's see what happens:

```
p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), alpha = 0.8)
p
```

[image]

The bars are overlapping because ggplot shifts bars horizontally *as if* they have a (stacked) width of 0.9 (*set* in `position_dodge`), while in fact the bars have a width of 1 (*set* in `geom_bar`).

If we use the *default* dodge values, the bars are shifted horizontally accurately according to the *set* bar width:

```
p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = "dodge", alpha = 0.8)
                                   # or: position = position_dodge(width = NULL)
```

---

Next we try to add some text to our plot using `geom_text`. We start with the default dodging `width` (`position_dodge(width = NULL)`), i.e. dodging is based on default element size.

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = grp, label = grp)) + theme_minimal()
p2 <- p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = NULL)) +
  geom_text(size = 10, position = position_dodge(width = NULL))
                  # or position = "dodge"    

p2
# Warning message:
#  Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`
```

[image]

The dodging of the text fails. What about the warning message, "Width is not defined"? Slightly cryptic. We need to consult the Details section of `?geom_text`:

> Note the "width" and "height" of a text element are 0,
> so stacking and dodging text will not work by default,
> [...]
> Obviously, labels do have height and width, but they are physical units, *not data units*.

So for `geom_text`, *the width of the individual elements* is zero. This is also the first 'official ggplot reference' to your second question: **The unit of `width` is in *data units***.

Let's look at the data used to render the text elements on the plot:

```
ggplot_build(p3)$data[[2]]
#       fill x y label PANEL group xmin xmax ymax colour size angle hjust vjust alpha family fontface lineheight
# 1 #F8766D 1 1     A     1     1    1    1    1  black   10     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
# 2 #00BFC4 1 1     B     1     2    1    1    1  black   10     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
```

Indeed, `xmin == xmax`; Thus, the width of the text element *in data units* is zero.

How to achieve correct dodging of the text element with width zero? From Examples in `?geom_text`:

> ggplot2 doesn't know you want to give the labels the same virtual width as the bars [...] So tell it:

Thus, in order for dodge to use the same width for `geom_text` elements as for the `geom_bar` elements when new positions are calculated, we need to *set* "the virtual dodging width in data units" of the text elements to the same width as the bars. We use the `width` argument of `position_dodge` to *set* the virtual width of the text element to 0.9 (i.e. the bar width in the example above):

```
p2 <- p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = NULL)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 10)
```

Check the data used for rendering `geom_text`:

```
ggplot_build(p2)$data[[2]]
#      fill     x y label PANEL group xmin xmax ymax colour size angle hjust vjust alpha family fontface lineheight
# 1 #F8766D 0.775 1     A     1     1 0.55 1.00    1  black   10     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
# 2 #00BFC4 1.225 1     B     1     2 1.00 1.45    1  black   10     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2
```

Now the text elements *have* a width in data units: `xmax - xmin = 0.9`, i.e. the same width as the bars. Thus, the dodge calculations will now be made *as if* the text elements have a certain width, here 0.9. Render the plot:

```
p2
```

[image]

The text is dodged correctly!

---

Similar to text, the width in data units of points (`geom_point`) and error bars (e.g. `geom_errorbar`) is zero. Thus, if you need to dodge such elements, you need to specify a relevant virtual width, on which dodge calculations then are based. See e.g. the Example section of `?geom_errorbar`:

> If you want to dodge bars and errorbars, you need to manually specify the dodge width [...] Because the bars and errorbars have different widths we need to specify how wide the objects we are dodging are

---

Here is an example with several x values on a continuous scale:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(10, 20, 50), each = 2),
                 y = 1,
                 grp = c("A", "B"))
```

Let's say we wish to create a dodged barplot with some text above each bar. First, just check a barplot only using the default dodging width:

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = grp, label = grp)) + theme_minimal()

p + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = NULL))
                         # or position = "dodge"
```

It works as expected. Then, add the text. We try to set the virtual width of the text element to the same as the width of the bars in the example above, i.e. we "guess" that the bars still have width of 0.9, and that we need to dodge the text elements *as if* they have a width of 0.9 as well:

```
p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 10)
```

[image]

Clearly, the dodging calculation for the bars is now based on a different width than 0.9 and setting the virtual width to 0.9 for the text element was a bad guess. So what *is* bar width here? Again, bar width is "[b]y default, set to 90% of the resolution of the data". Check the resolution:

```
resolution(df$x)
# [1] 10
```

Thus, the width of the (default stacked) bars, on which *their* new, dodged position is calculated, is now `0.9 * 10 = 9`. Thus, to dodge the bars and their corresponding text 'hand in hand', we need to set the virtual width of also the text elements to 9:

```
p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 9), size = 10)
```

[image]

---

In our final example, we have a categorical x axis, just a 'factor version' of the x values from above.

```
df <- data.frame(x = factor(rep(c(10, 20, 50), each = 2)),
                 y = 1,
                 grp = c("A", "B"))
```

In R, factors are internally a set of integer codes with a "levels" attribute. And from `?resolution`:

> If x is an integer vector, then it is assumed to represent a discrete variable, and the resolution is 1.

By now, we know that when `resolution` is 1, the default width of the bars is 0.9. Thus, on a categorical x axis, the default width for `geom_bar` is 0.9, and we need to set the dodging `width` for `geom_text` accordingly:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = grp, label = grp)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  # or: position = position_dodge(width = NULL)
  # or: position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: You deserve a medal for this answer.

Comment: @brittenb Thank you for your kind feedback. I'm a bit worried about my mental health though, spending the entire Saturday morning on an answer like this...

Comment: We've all been there, haha!

Comment: Wow, such a detailed and educational answer, explaining not just the principles but also the implications. I'd just hold on to the tick mark for a while so that other people are incentivized to take a look at this question and answer!

Comment: great answer, but can I add 1 more request? what if we wanted the geomtext dodged with width 0.9 but we also wanted it in the center of the bar? what parameter are we missing?

Comment: Do you mean vertically centered in the bar? Try to add `aes(y = y / 2)` to `geom_text`.