# Add labels to geom_bar by fill location

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(type=c("A","B","D","A","C","D","B","C","D","E"),
                 count=as.integer(runif(10,100,200)),
                 sample=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),stringsAsFactors=F)
df$type <- factor(df$type,levels=unique(sort(df$type)))
```

which I plot using `geom_bar`:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=sample,y=count,fill=type))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

My question is how to add `df$type` as a label on top of each bar?

Adding:

```
geom_text(aes(label=type,hjust=0),position=("dodge"))
```

obviously doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the width argument in position\_dodge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=sample,y=count,fill=type))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(label=type,hjust=0, vjust=-0.1),position=position_dodge(width = 1))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I played around with hjust but can't get the labels to be centered with respect to their bars (hjust=0.5 comes close but not enough). Any idea?

Comment: @dan you can change both the width and hjust to have the texts to your desired positions.

Comment: To centre the labels, use `width = 0.9` and remove `hjust = 0`