# Points of dotplot are not centered on the corresponding barplot bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this table:

```
a   b   c   d
A   55  2   0.07
A   123 1   0.05
B   222 2   0.04
B   234 1   0.03
C   233 2   0.03
C   187 1   0.04
D   564 2   0.06
D   325 1   0.01
E   112 2   0.02
E   105 1   0.01
```

I'm plotting a barplot with dots using `geom_bar` and `geom_point`. For some reason, the dots are not centered in the middle of the bar. Can somebody help with this?

My code:

```
ggplot(table, aes(x=a, y=d, fill=as.factor(c))) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
geom_point(aes(y = b / 10000), 
           position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: `geom_bar(stat = 'identity', …)` ➝ `geom_col(…)`.

Comment: Also maybe this:  `...position = position_dodge(width = .9))`?

Comment: [What is the width argument in position_dodge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge)

Comment: You need to use the same width for the dodge in both `geom_point` and `geom_bar`.

Comment: i've tried with Konrad, s_t and Gregor tips and didn't work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @s_t, you have to write:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=a, y=d, fill=as.factor(c))) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_point(aes(y = b / 10000), 
             position = position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

**Data**

```r
d = data.frame(a = sort(rep(LETTERS[1:5],2)),
               b = c(55,123,222,234,233,187,564,325,112,105),
               c = rep(c(2,1),5),
               d = c(0.07,0.05,0.04,0.03,0.03,0.04,0.06,0.01,0.02,0.01))
```