# align geom_text with geom_boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following two data sets:

```
behaviorm <- structure(list(sentential_connective = c("IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", 
"IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", 
"IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", 
"IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", "IF", 
"IF", "IF", "IF"), mentioned_object = c("Same", "Same", "Same", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", 
"Same", "Same", "Same", "Same", "Same"), agent_mood = c("Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", "Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad"), Chosen_Box = c("SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", 
"SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "SD", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", 
"CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "CS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", "DD", 
"DD", "DD", "DD"), participant = c("a01", "a02", "a03", "a04", 
"a05", "a06", "a07", "a08", "a09", "a10", "a01", "a02", "a03", 
"a04", "a05", "a06", "a07", "a08", "a09", "a10", "a01", "a02", 
"a03", "a04", "a05", "a06", "a07", "a08", "a09", "a10", "a01", 
"a02", "a03", "a04", "a05", "a06", "a07", "a08", "a09", "a10"
), Counts = c(12L, 8L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 12L, 9L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 
224L, 225L, 226L), class = "data.frame")


res <- structure(list(sentential_connective = c("IF", "IF", "IF", "IF"
), mentioned_object = c("Same", "Same", "Same", "Same"), agent_mood = c("Sad", 
"Sad", "Sad", "Sad"), Chosen_Box = c("SD", "CS", "SS", "DD"), 
    statistic = c(54, 0, 0, 8), p.value = c(0.00362357852661936, 
    0.999052845531107, 0.999052845531107, 0.937942586194492), 
    Sig = c("*", "", "", ""), Counts = c(12L, 1L, 1L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
73L, 145L, 217L))
```

And the following code I used to do the plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
b <- ggplot()
b <- b + aes(x = sentential_connective, y = Counts)
b <- b + geom_boxplot(aes(color = Chosen_Box), data = behaviorm, outlier.color = NA)
b <- b + geom_text(   aes(label = Sig),        data = res, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9), size = 5)
b
```

In the resulting graph, however, the label from the `res` file is not correctly aligned with the boxplot from the `behaviorm` file.

I've tried the suggestions explained in [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge) and did not succeed.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `sentential_connective` is a single factor `IF`, instead of using `x = sentential_connective`, you should use `x = Chosen_Box` to get boxplot aligned with their group and re-use this `x` to plot the label from the dataset `res`.

So, a code like that should work

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(behaviorm, aes(x = Chosen_Box, y = Counts))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = Chosen_Box), outlier.color = NA) +
  geom_text(data = res, aes(x = Chosen_Box, label = Sig, y = 13), size = 10)+
  ylim(0,14)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT: Adding geom_text for multiple variables**

Based on your comments, you have at least two groups defined in `sentential_connective` and you would like to be able to keep this as the x parameter.

So, to do it, I first duplicate your data in order to have two factor levels for `sentential_connective` in both datasets:

```r
behavior2 = behaviorm
behavior2$sentential_connective <- "IF2"
behav = rbind(behaviorm, behavior2)

res2 = res
res2$sentential_connective = "IF2"
RES = rbind(res2,res)
```

And for the plot, you were close to the solution by using `position_dodge()`, except that you have to use it also for `geom_boxplot`.

```r
ggplot(behav, aes(x = sentential_connective, y = Counts, color = Chosen_Box))+
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0.8), outlier = NA)+
  geom_text(data = RES, aes( x = sentential_connective, y =13, label = Sig, group = Chosen_Box), size = 10, color = "black", position=position_dodge(width=0.8))+
  ylim(0,14)
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Thank you very much. But the data I gave is a simplified one of my original data, where the variable `sentential_connective` contains two levels. So it would be better to keep the information of sentential connectives in the graph. Thanks.

Comment: Got it ! I edited my answer, it should solve your issue. Let me know if it is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems that `group = Chosen_Box` is crucial for the result

Comment: Yes it is ! but the `position_dodge()` in both `geom_boxplot` and `geom_text` is really important too. Glad to be able to help you !