# How to overcome on the overlapping of the labels for bars in graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, label

I am trying to using ggplot2. The problem I faced there is labels of bars are up and down for each two bars of the graph. I would like to be each label on its own bar. I would like you to help me in fix this problem.

Also, I would like to know if there is a possibility to add "k$" to the label to each bar. I would like to know if there is a possibility to put the indicators (Actual and Budget) on the top of the graph.

This is my code:

```
library (ggplot2)

library(plotly)

library(readxl)

library(tidyverse)

df =read_excel("C:/Fall 2020 - Clarkson University/Information Visualization/Assignments/Assignment2/a2-DeptYearlyPerf.xls")

df2= df %>% pivot_longer(-Dept.,names_to="category", values_to="amount")

df3=df2 %>% separate(category,into=c("qtr","bud_or_act"),sep=" ")

df3 %>% ggplot(aes(x=qtr,y= amount,fill=bud_or_act, label= amount, width=.7)) +
  
  geom_col(position="dodge") +facet_wrap(~Dept.) +
  
  geom_text(size=3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data hence I can not help you with the code however you may find the [ggrepel package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html) helpful.

Or you can try:

```
df2= Book1 %>% pivot_longer(-Dept,names_to="category", values_to="amount")

df3=df2 %>% separate(category,into=c("qtr","bud_or_act"),sep=" ")

df3 %>% ggplot(aes(x=qtr,y= amount,fill=qtr, label= amount, width=.7)) +
  
geom_bar(stat='identity',position="dodge") +facet_wrap(~Dept) +
  
geom_text(size=3,hjust = 0.5)
```

Result on my computer with hypothetical numbers:
https://ibb.co/DrSsXCG

Comment: The data and the graph have been attached to my question

Comment: Just made changes since I could not see the plots initially.

Comment: The labels were up and down for each two bars of the graph. I would like to be each label on its own bar. I can update my question and send you the graph if you wish.

Comment: Can you try to align with hjust parameter?

Comment: I update the question so you can see the graph I got

Comment: I tried to use "hjust" parameter and I got this error. Error in position_stack(hjust = 0.5) : unused argument (hjust = 0.5)

Comment: Can you try: geom_text(size=3, position=position_dodge(), hjust=-0.5)

Comment: I tried to do that, but I got this Warning message:
Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`

Comment: This should help you :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge/35102486. by convering it to position = "dodge"

Comment: There is overlapping between the labels

Comment: I tried this df3 %>% ggplot(aes(x=qtr,y= amount,fill=bud_or_act, label= amount, width=.7)) +
  
  geom_col(position="dodge") +facet_wrap(~Dept.) +
  
  geom_text(size=3, position_dodge(width = NULL), hjust=-0.5)

Comment: but I am still having overlapping between labels

Comment: Still overlapping with  position = "dodge", hjust=-0.5?

Comment: Yes, when I write those line code:df3 %>% ggplot(aes(x=qtr,y= amount,fill=bud_or_act, label= amount, width=.7)) +
  
  geom_col(position="dodge") +facet_wrap(~Dept.) +
  
  geom_text(size=3, position = "dodge", hjust=-0.5)

Comment: I got this Warning message:
Width not defined. Set with `position_dodge(width = ?)`

Comment: Just reproduced on my laptop with some hypothetical numbers and worked fine with me. 
`df2= Book1 %>% pivot_longer(-Dept,names_to="category", values_to="amount")

df3=df2 %>% separate(category,into=c("qtr","bud_or_act"),sep=" ")

df3 %>% ggplot(aes(x=qtr,y= amount,fill=qtr, label= amount, width=.7)) +
  
geom_bar(stat='identity',position="dodge") +facet_wrap(~Dept) +
  
geom_text(size=3,hjust = 0.5)`