# How to align overlap of Boxplot and Violinplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot signal intensity per timepoint in a  violinplot then adding box-plots to it, to give more info. The dataframe has data for two duplicates A and B. So far I managed to create the graph but the boxplot is not overlapping the violin there is a slight shift.  Any suggestions how fix that please?

```
Violin_plot <- ggplot(DF_combine, aes(factor(Duplicate),x=Time, y=signal))+ 
              geom_violin(aes(fill=Duplicate),width=0.6,color="#535352")+
              geom_boxplot(aes(fill=Duplicate),color="#535352",width=0.2,notch = T) +
              scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

[image: current graph]

Comment: Try adding `position = position_dodge(0.9)` in both `geom_violin()` and `geom_boxplot()`. (The 0.9 modifies the width, you might have to drop the "width" arguments, I am not sure.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and  did not complain about the width arg. If I may ask why position dodge 0.9 ?

Comment: I also had a similar problem recently and someone suggested me to read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge (although I did not have the time yet to read through it myself ;;)

Comment: @Zoe, your solutions worked. you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `position = position_dodge(0.9)` in both `geom_violin()` and `geom_boxplot()`:

```
ggplot(DF_combine, aes(factor(Duplicate),x = Time, y = signal)) +
    geom_violin(aes(fill = Duplicate),width = 0.6, color = "#535352", position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Duplicate), color = "#535352", width = 0.2, notch = T, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

See [What is the width argument in position_dodge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889766/what-is-the-width-argument-in-position-dodge) for an explanation.